# LWJGL Javadoc with descriptions?

Tags: java, eclipse, opengl, lwjgl

Feel lack about LWJGL's Javadoc descriptions in Eclipse. I mean you can [download a javadoc from sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/java-game-lib/files/Official%20Releases/LWJGL%202.9.0/) but attributes and methods for example in GL11 there are without description. As a newbie I want to know whats the assignment of each attribute and method without searching everytime. After fast research I found hopefully the way I can solve that little problem - [OpenGL Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd368808%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). The only thing is left as I thought is to copy-paste one-by-one what is not easy but possible I guess.. I don't know how exactly to do that. So I did go to my project in eclipse and search in LWJGL's packages for easy way to do that and I found curious thing, not sure if this what will help, anyway, in each .class file each attribute and method has comment line with something like this

```
// Field descriptor #544 I
```

So, first way I see is to add descriptions by editing that somewhere(**if you know where tell me**).
Second way I am thinking about is Attach Source option that I can use in each .class file. I don't understand what is the purpose of that button but maybe it is possible to take descriptions from microsoft msdn and attach them somehow to LWJGL? Does anyone know how to solve that?

Answer (score 1):

you can use this, is quite good, it contains almost all what you need to know.

http://www.cs.rutgers.edu/~decarlo/428/glman.html

Comment: great link. it's not an answer to my question.. anyway, thank's